# Interpolated String from a string in Javascript possible without eval?

Tags: javascript

Say you have

```
window.something = 123; 
var code = 'window.something'
var str = `${code}`

console.log(str)
```

Naturally that will output *window.someting*

Is there a way to declare an interpolated String and get the string to be evaluated?

Something like `new InterpolatedString('window.something')` and actually get whatever is in there? For the current context?

I know this might be much to ask for, but since the language is interpreted, they could have exposed this but I don't believe they have :/

Comment: *"...but since the language is interpreted..."* It *can* be. It isn't necessarily.

Comment: 1. This sounds like `eval` 2. Don't use `eval`.

Comment: Also relevant: [“Variable” variables in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5187530)

Comment: In the scenario you've shown, yes, you can do it without `eval` because `window` is a property name on the global object; see the linked question's answers for how. If you wanted to do this where the first segment was an arbitrary in-scope variable that wasn't a property on an object you could access, then no, you can't do it without `eval` or its cousin `new Function`.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder it would have been terrificly convienient for use in a template engine. I am not sure how they execute code. Like underscore, and others. Eval is slow. Personally, I interpret the code within but that is with limits on what can be done. Maybe there is a javascript code by string executioner that can parse, you know?

Comment: What part of that answer did you want me to look at? For this example yes, it is simple. I can parse that. In theory an interpolated string can actually have arbitrary code to my experience thus far. I am not sure of the performance of it, but surely it has to be more performant than eval. I am not sure how they differ in implementation but they seem awefully similar.